# Need help identifying component (diode?) - black, rectangular, marked 100 D95 with [ + ] at one end

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

I need some help identifying this component. It's similar to one of the components that burnt to the bottom left of the image, so I need to replace it.

It is on the laptop charging circuit, if that helps. It looks like a diode, but I've never seen one with that [ + ] symbol.

[image: photo of PCB with unknown component marked]

Answer (score 6):

It appears to be a 100uF/20V Panasonic [20TQC100MYF](https://na.industrial.panasonic.com/products/capacitors/polymer-capacitors/lineup/poscap-tantalum-polymer/series/13138/model/13219) or [20TDC100MYF](https://api.pim.na.industrial.panasonic.com/file_stream/main/fileversion/8553) tantalum polymer capacitor ([POSCAP™](https://api.pim.na.industrial.panasonic.com/file_stream/main/fileversion/183089)). D is the voltage code.

Answer (score 2):

That's a tantalum capacitor, not a diode. Most likely 100 μF from the marking.

Comment: Yep. Why wouldn't I thought it was a capacitor as I've never seen one like that. Thanks

Comment: @AlphaAdhito Tantalum capacitors are rather uncommon these days, though they used to be more common. They're smaller than aluminum electrolytics and can handle higher temperatures (as the electrolytic isn't water-based), but they're more expensive and their failure modes involve bursting into flames (so they need to be used with care). The availability of modern high-capacitance MLCCs (a type of ceramic capacitor) has relegated tantalum capacitors to basically nothing but very small form-factor power supplies, like those in mobile devices.

Comment: 100% concur about the "bursting into flames" failure mode as in my case. Luckily nothing except the plastic cover that got burnt.